Is there something for extending rules in monaco editor, similar to ace editor oop inheritance
I'm migrating an existing Ace editor project to Monaco Editor, which has few highlight rules set for them, and are used depending on instances. I want to achieve something similar to this in Monaco Editor.
First I thought of simply adding the rules to each new instance, but this would have caused various custom languages being created, which wouldn't be the case if we could extend it. I went through this issue on github for the same. But In my scenario, I don't want to extends upon an existing language, but more on two different rulesets. Another option is to write a custom function to extend upon a given use case and combine them together. But I feel like that's a suboptimal method for the same.
